# Thread Safety in Jpa Entity Listener class

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, thread-safety

I am using jpa entity listener and spring boot in my project . Before calling update method of spring jpa repository my `@PreUpdate` method is called and where  I am fetching `oldEventObject` object before updating the database. But after update to database my @PostUpdate method is called where I am making use of `oldEventObject` Object to check whether the object state have changed or not . My question is whether `oldEventObject`  Object is thread safe or not . If not Do i have to make my Listener class Prototype or what should i do to make it thread safe

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XYZ")
@EntityListeners({XYZPublisher.class})
public class XYZ implements Serializable {}
```

**Listener class**

```
    @Component
    public class XYZPublisher {
    
      private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XYZPublisher.class);
final ThreadLocal<XYZ> oldEventThreadLocal=new ThreadLocal<>();
   
      @Autowired
      private EventPublisher eventPublisher;
    
      @Autowired
      private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    

      @Nullable
      public XYZ getOldEventObject() {
        return oldEventObject;
      }
    
      public void setOldEventObject(@Nullable XYZ oldEventObject) {
        this.oldEventObject= oldEventObject;
      }
    
      
    
      @PreUpdate
      @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
      public void preUpdateEvent(XYZ evenType) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(entityManagerFactory)) {
          EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
          Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
          XYZ oldEvent= session.get(XYZ .class, XYZ .getId());
          oldEventThreadLocal.set(oldEvent);
        }
      }
    
      @PostUpdate
      public void publishUpdateEvent(XYZ newEvent) {
     XYZ oldEvent= oldEventThreadLocal.get();
     timeEventTypeThreadLocal.remove();
        if (Objects.nonNull(eventPublisher) && Objects.nonNull(oldTimeEventType)) {
          List<EntityChangedDataItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
          String newName = newEvent.getName();
          String oldName = oldEvent.getName();
          if (!(Objects.equals(newName, oldName))) {
            EntityChangedDataItem entityChangedDataItem = new EntityChangedDataItem();
            entityChangedDataItem.setAttributeName("name");
            entityChangedDataItem.setOldValue(oldName);
            entityChangedDataItem.setNewValue(newName);
            items.add(entityChangedDataItem);
          }
    
          if (!(Objects.equals(newEvent.getCode(), oldEvent.getCode()))) {
            EntityChangedDataItem entityChangedDataItem = new EntityChangedDataItem();
            entityChangedDataItem.setAttributeName("code");
            entityChangedDataItem.setOldValue(oldEvent.getCode());
            entityChangedDataItem.setNewValue(newEvent.getCode());
            items.add(entityChangedDataItem);
          }
    
          if (!(Objects.equals(newEvent.isActive(), oldEvent.isActive()))) {
            EntityChangedDataItem entityChangedDataItem = new EntityChangedDataItem();
            entityChangedDataItem.setAttributeName("active");
            entityChangedDataItem.setOldValue(Boolean.toString(oldEvent.isActive()));
            entityChangedDataItem.setNewValue(Boolean.toString(newEvent.isActive()));
            items.add(entityChangedDataItem);
          }
          publishUpdatedItemsToKafka(items);
        } else {
          log.error(PUBLISHED_ERROR);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't thread-safe, you are keeping state, the `oldTimeEventType` making it scoped prototype won't help. If multiple entities are updated you don't know what happend to the `oldTimeEventType` could be that it was changed mid-flight to something else leading to weird events being send on Kafka.  You might be better of by tapping into hibernate and use that event system. That way you get the old and new state in 1 go (this is how Hibernate Envers works as well).

Comment: @M.Deinum what if i use threadlocal final ThreadLocal<TimeEventType> timeEventTypeThreadLocal=new ThreadLocal<>(); and use it preupdate like this timeEventTypeThreadLocal.set(timeEventOld); and in postupdate like this TimeEventType oldTimeEventType= timeEventTypeThreadLocal.get();
    timeEventTypeThreadLocal.remove();

Comment: That could work, but i'm not sure the order of calling is garantueed so you might end up with weird issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thx for the valuable answer i am little confused here how does order of calling in Thread local variable matter lets say we 5 calling thread each thread should have there own timeEventType object passed in preupdate method. whenever session.get() will be called will get corresponding thread object from the database will be pulled and then  we are setting this value in thread local. I have update my code please let me know wether this is correct or not

Comment: If you are updating **5 items** in a **single** thread is the order of calling pre and post guaranteed. So is it pre-1, post 1 or pre-1,2,3,4,5 and post 5,4,3,2,1. Because if the order is different you are in for a treat. Even if it is pre1,2,3,4,5 and post 1,2,3,4,5 you are in for a treat as you are now comparing 5 and 1 and not 1 and 1. So there are certain dangers entailed.

Comment: @M.Deinum NO I am not updating any item here  all i need to get the old database value before update in preupdate method and store it somewhere . So after update and transaction commited by jpa my postmethod will called that is where I am reading both  old value and new updated value for that particular id and comparing it it there is any change in value if yes i will publish to kafka

Comment: Please read. If in your code (the JPA stuff) you are updating multiple items in a single thread you are screwed when using a `ThreadLocal`. It will only work if you update a single item in a transaction, as soon as you proces a list with multiple items it might fail depending on the implementation in hibernate. I really would suggest adding a Hibernate based `EntityListener` which will make it thread safe and a lot easier to implement.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Thanks for the answer I have got your point here. I am seeing hibernate event system how will i get old and new event in one transaction ? because hibernate event system have same kind of interface pre and post interface which  i need to implement  with different method  i need to implement any references or resources i can look into it

Comment: With the hibernate one you get a `PostUpdateEvent` this events contains **both** the old and new state for the entity. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/PostUpdateEvent.html. When it is an insert there is only current state and with a delete only old.